# I forgot my sudo password on Debian

Tags: passwords, sudo, recovery

I need my root password to get allegro installed. I can't boot Debian neither I don't know what else I can do. Please, send help.

Comment: Have you considered reinstalling Debian? Not sure you can do much if you forgot your root password.

Comment: At this point, I guess  it's the only possibility left for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you use sudo, it expects your own user password, not that of root.

Comment: then it's my user password I can't remember at the moment :) So, is it any way to get it back without uninstalling Debian?

Comment: If you auto login without needing to enter a password, then you need to have a LiveCD so you can remove your existing password, then login without one, then create one.   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165514